# How can one configure Sky Force Reloaded so that taking one's finger off doesn't slow down the game?

Tags: android, sky-force-reloaded

In [Sky Force Reloaded](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.SkyForceReloaded2016&hl=en_US&gl=US), by default, when one takes one's finger off the screen, the game enters paused mode, where time is significantly slowed down. How can one configure Sky Force Reloaded so that taking one's finger off doesn't slow down the game?

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.